# Hide the "Download a copy" for sharepoint list items

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-actions

I want to hide the "Download a Copy" option that comes when we click the "Send To" option.  How can we achieve this? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not a matter of security you could do it with css:

```
#ID_DownloadACopy{display:none;}
```

Or Jquery (haven't tested):

```
$('#ID_DownloadACopy').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked for me:

```
<style>
#Ribbon\.Documents\.Copies-LargeMedium-0{display:none;}
li[text="Download a Copy"] {
display:none;
}
</style>
```